# Can a string claim from an external IdP's JWT be coerced into a single element stringCollection?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a client whose IdP issues JWT's with group claims in the following format:

```json
"groups": [
   "Domain Users",
   "US Users",
   "Administrators"
]
```

But when there is only a single group:

```json
"groups": "Domain Users"
```

Now obviously, this is bad practice, but we have little to no control over our client's decision to use inconsistent data types. As expected, B2C throws an exception when trying to parse a claim it expects to be a stringCollection but is actually a string.

Is there any workaround for this scenario?

EDIT:

Here is the groups ClaimType as defined in TrustFrameworkExtensions:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="groups">
    <DisplayName>Groups</DisplayName>
    <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
    <AdminHelpText>User's groups.</AdminHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

And the OutputClaim in the external IdP TechnicalProfile:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" PartnerClaimType="group" />
```

Comment: Can you show how B2C parse the "groups" claim currently? And what exception message is thrown?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel and please follow this document https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups and let us know if you need more information.

Comment: @AllenWu, I added additional context to the OP to show the defined ClaimType and OutputClaim. The exception message when the partner claim is a string is something like "The 'group' claim with datatype 'string' cannot be converted to 'stringCollection' because the JWT from the IdP is sometimes a string ("Domain Users") and other times a stringCollection (["Domain Users", "US Users", "Admins"]).

Comment: @Jit_MSFT, Thanks for your response, but the issue relates to federating with an external IdP whose JWT's we have no control over. The exception occurs between B2C and the external IdP, not B2C and our relying party web app.

Comment: Did you try with `AddItemToStringCollection`? It can add a string to a new or existing stringCollection. See the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations#additemtostringcollection.

Comment: @AllenWu Unfortunately I cannot use a claims transformation because the problem is mapping the groups claim to the partner claim which can either be a string or a stringCollection.

Comment: @Jit_MSFT Any updates on this? This appears to be the way AD FS and other federated identity systems issue collection-type claims--as a string if there is only one element, or an array if there is more than one. This precedent is described in [RFC7519 4.1.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3). Is B2C unable to handle this standard practice?